# Is it possible to name a database table column with the word 'type' without incurring into problems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, naming

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and I would like to know *if it is possible to name a database table column with the word `type` without incurring into problems* (I know that the "type" word is used in [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)...). **Is it?**

And if I would like to use, for example, a database table name as `article_type`, what kind of problems can I have (without using a Polymorphic Association)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes it is.

You can use the `type` column if you define this in your model:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = nil
end
```

Having a table called `article_type` wouldn't matter to Rails. It's only the `type` column that it is protective of.

Comment: If I override the `self.inheritance_column = nil` I will not be able to use the the Single Table Inheritance... is it right?

Comment: Yes, you would only override this in the case that you *didn't* want to use STI.

Comment: You really shouldn't update the question with *more* question... but updated anyway.

Comment: You are right but I updated the question with further information concerning the same subject.

Comment: You can set `inheritance_column` to some other non nil value that doesn't clash with any of the column names you want if you want to retain the ability to use STI